# Transparent blurred view is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiblureffect

I'd like to apply layer on top of ImageView that slightly blurrs it.
I put a view on top of imageView, subclass it as follows:

```
class BlurredView: UIView {
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
   }
}
```

The result is quite different from what I expected.

[image]

How to customize it to make this blur much lighter, so the picture still shows some details?

Comment: Have you tried changing the alpha of the blur view?

Comment: This way it is transparent but the blur effect does not seem to be applied

Comment: You cannot really customise the effect of `UIVisualEffectView`. To get the blurring you expect, you have to implement blurring yourself. `Core Image` is the search term that should help you.

Comment: I agree with @dasdom - Core Image has several blur filters you could use. But try one thing first - I see you have UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight. Try using .light instead. Believe it or not, that probably gives you more of what you want.

Comment: One more suggestion - if you are subclassing something to create a blur effect, go straight to it: subclass UIVisualEffectView.

Comment: @dasdom Could you provide any resources that can help me out? Everything I found so far is about blurring an image - I want to create blurring layer which when put on top of the image,  blurrs it accordingly

Comment: I have tested it, changing the opacity of UIVisualEffectView (not the UIBlurEffect) is the right answer.
In the other hand, in your code example, don't forget to remove the previous added UIVisualEffectView to avoid a stack of UIVisualEffectView each time the view is redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387306/chrstpsln mentioned in the comment, this can be achieved by changing the alpha of the UIVisualEffectView.

As a bonus, you can add a fade animation to make the transition feel smoother.

Heres an example of how you can add this effect to any viewController through an extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addBlurEffect() {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)

        let blurVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurVisualEffectView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds


        blurVisualEffectView.alpha = 0.1

        // Bonus animation - Or just set the alpha higher
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            blurVisualEffectView.alpha = 0.90
        }

        view.addSubview(blurVisualEffectView)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let viewController = UIViewController() 
viewController.addBlurEffect()
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't change the blur amount, the only thing you can do is to change the blur effect style:

```
UIBlurEffectStyle.light
UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight
UIBlurEffectStyle.dark
```

Try to change the blur effect alpha. Also, since your image is light, you should use the light style and not the extra light in order to not lose details.

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
blurEffect.alpha = 0.95
```

Comment: UIBlurEffect  has no alpha property !